# Question of apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe

I already asked similar question in the following: [meaning of plural of plural v.s. singular of plural](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147047/meaning-of-plural-of-plural-v-s-singular-of-plural/147049#147049).

For example, when I want to express crash among many cars, I used ***cars' crashing***.
However, in the above link (my similar question), I saw the answer of cars crashing is correct, but cars' crashing is not correct.

Can someone explain about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cars' crashing** sounds like the act of crashing is in the possession of the cars. I wouldn't say that's a common phrasing. Sounds kind of weired.

**cars crashing**, on the other hand, is the noun **cars** plus the present participle form of the verb **to crash**. This means that the cars are in the process of crashing.